# Is it possible to style each level of a nested list horizontally using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-position

I'm trying to style a nested list such that each level is displayed (horizontally) in its *own* container, with sublists then displayed (horizontally) in *subsequent* containers; at most one sublist will exist at each level, so the parent item can always be unambiguously indicated.

The only way I can see to ensure that certain items (namely those that come after a sibling with a sublist) are in the correct "row" for their level (rather than being rendered after the sublist) is to remove sublists from normal flow with `position: absolute;`.  This gets me pretty close to what I want, however I then need to move the sublist into position—but its correct vertical position depends on the height of the container for its parent level: for example, the parent level might contain so many items that the list wraps within its container and expands the height.

I know that I can move the sublist into position using JavaScript, but is there a pure CSS way of accomplishing what I want (whether that involves some trickery by which an absolutely-positioned block can be positioned relative to another element, or else preventing siblings from appearing after blocks that precede them in normal flow)?

Example below—

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.level2 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.expanded {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="expanded">
      Two
      <ul class="level2">
        <li>Alpha</li>
        <li>Beta Gamma Delta</li>
        <li>Epsilon</li>
        <li>Zeta Eta Theta</li>
        <li>Iota</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Three Four</li>
    <li>Five Six Seven</li>
    <li>Eight Nine Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are after...do you have an image of the desired result?

Comment: @Paulie_D: If you run the snippet, you can see the problem (the sublist is atop the second row of the parent).

Comment: @Dennis: I'm not trying to create any elements that aren't there.  If further elements are required, I could add them into the markup (although that sounds like it'd be mixing presentation with information structure to me).  I'm not trying to create a dropdown menu, so I'm not sure whether that's relevant?

Comment: I can see the snippet but it's still not clear exactly what you are after (at least to me). you need submenus to open in a "drawer" below the top level with any 'extra' top level items below that drawer? Then "NO"...not possible with CSS except possibly flexbox and I'm doubtful about that.

Comment: @Paulie_D: The parent list level (white background) counts up to eleven; however, two of its items ("EIGHT NINE TEN" and "ELEVEN") are hidden behind the sublist (grey background).  I want the sublist to be positioned BELOW the parent level, but such position depends on how the parent level is rendered (and in particular, whether its contents wrap).

Comment: Oh....you mean like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/f4uxwj5w/ and http://jsfiddle.net/f4uxwj5w/2/

Comment: @eggyal, sorry I misinterpreted your question. Now I get what you mean, let me work on a fiddle and try to fix it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always set the position of the parent `ul` as relative and then the submenu can have an absolute position of `top:100%` which will always position it below the parent menu.

From MDN

> For absolutely positioned elements, the top, right, bottom, and left
>   properties specify offsets from the edge of the element's containing
>   block (what the element is positioned relative to). The margin of the
>   element is then positioned inside these offsets.

As follows

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
ul {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative; /* positioning context */
}
.level2 {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:100%; /* always at the bottom */
    margin-top: 2em; /* additional spacing */
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.expanded {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li>One</li>
        <li class="expanded">Two
            <ul class="level2">
                <li>Alpha</li>
                <li>Beta Gamma Delta</li>
                <li>Epsilon</li>
                <li>Zeta Eta Theta</li>
                <li>Iota</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Three Four</li>
        <li>Five Six Seven</li>
        <li>Eight Nine Ten</li>
        <li>Eleven</li>
        <li>Twelve</li>
        <li>Thirteen</li>
        <li>Fourteen</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooh, this is interesting.  When specifying `top: 100%;`, what is it 100% *of*?

Comment: 100% of the height of the `relative` parent.

Comment: Well, then that's exactly what I want!  Thank you.  Any chance you can cite authority for that?

Comment: That only says that `top: 50px` would be `50px` from the container; not that a percentage is relative to the height of the container...

Comment: That's included by extension...`top:25%` would be 25% from the top edge...and so on.

Comment: 25% of *what* from the top edge?  You say the parent container's height, and it certainly looks like that, but I'd love to see it written somewhere...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props TOP - "Percentages:   refer to height of containing block"